# Code in synchronized block

Tags: java, multithreading

Is there any difference of placing `timlesProc(100);` inside or outside `synchronized` block like shown commented line in ThreadA.

According to my understanding there is no difference, because both threads are in running mode and both can be executed in the same time. But according experiments, when `timlesProc(100);` is inside `synchronized` - it always runs first, then `b.sync.wait();` and no 'wait forever' problem. When `timlesProc(100);` outside `synchronized` - I always get 'waiting forever'. Why it is so, or my understanding is not correct?

```
class ThreadA {
public static void timlesProc(int count)
{
         for(int i=0;i<count;i++) 
           {
              System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+ Integer.toString(i));
           }
}

    public static void main(String [] args) {
         ThreadB b = new ThreadB();

         b.start();

         //timlesProc(100);
         synchronized(b.sync) 
         {
            timlesProc(100);


            try 
            {
               System.out.println("Waiting for b to complete...");
               b.sync.wait();
               System.out.println("waiting done");

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}



         }




     }
  }




class ThreadB extends Thread {   

     Integer sync = new Integer(1);
     public void run() {


        synchronized(sync) 
        {
           sync.notify();
            System.out.println("notify done");

        }  


     }
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

You have a race condition. If the `timlesProc` method is outside the `synchronized`, it's **very probable** that you will have a context switch and the other `Thread` will be able to execute acquiring the lock and notifying the `main` Thread (even if it wasn't waiting). Then when you get to

```
b.sync.wait();
```

you wait forever because there is nothing left to `notify()` it.

If you put the `timlesProc` inside the `synchronized`, you reach the `wait()` and then get notified. The program then finishes.

See [Cruncher's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19031510/438154) for another possibility of your program waiting forever.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, even if the `timlesProc` call is inside the synchronized block, there is still a race condition, just less likely to happen.

If `b.start()` happens, and it aquires the sync lock before the main thread, then it will still notify first causing the same problem that Sotirios Delimanolis mentions in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19031171/code-in-synchronized-block/19031341#19031341).

Comment: Right, I missed that possibility.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis is this less likely to happen with a single processor system vs multiple?

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the processors. It's really up to the `Thread` scheduler.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis but if the Thread Scheduler has more processors to use for scheduling, there's more chance of these running concurrently right? If they can run at the same time that should give a higher chance of a race condition, than context switching on that exact instruction, right? I'm not really a synchronization expert. Always looking to learn ^.^

Comment: I'm no expert :|. The way I see it the scheduler allocates  X clock-time for each Thread. Having more or less processors wont affect that.